# Can not run DaVinci Resolve Free on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, amd-processor, davinci-resolve

I've installed DaVinci Resolve free 16.2.2 on my Ubuntu 20.04. Now I'm trying to tun it but it does not work for some reason.

Here is a log when I'm trying to run the app from terminal

```
➜  bin ./resolve 
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c005, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c006, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c007, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= 2282, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= 8, Option= 0
PnlMsgActionStringAdapter Already in Table: Code= 615e, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
16.2.2 (#012) Linux/Clang
Main thread starts: F7622C40
[0x7f27f7622c40] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2020-06-13 12:39:23,182 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[0x7f27f7622c40] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2020-06-13 12:39:23,183 | Loaded log config from /home/banha/.local/share/DaVinciResolve/configs/log-conf.xml
[0x7f27f7622c40] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2020-06-13 12:39:23,183 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1]    3056 abort (core dumped)  ./resolve
```

Also, here is crash log

```
#TIME Sat Jun 13 12:39:23 2020 - Uptime 00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss)
#PROGRAM_NAME DaVinci Resolve v16.2.2.012 (Linux/Clang)

./resolve() [0x54bef69]
./resolve() [0x54be75a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0) [0x7f27fcb523c0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb) [0x7f27fa8b618b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x12b) [0x7f27fa895859]
./resolve(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0x15d) [0x7229f3d]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x22086) [0x7f282d21b086]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x21a27) [0x7f282d21aa27]
./resolve() [0x1fb2ddc]
./resolve() [0x1fb25a9]
./resolve() [0x1fac2cc]
./resolve() [0x1f7895c]
./resolve() [0x1f75a6e]
./resolve() [0x1f7444f]
./resolve() [0x1f73cf8]
./resolve() [0x1f899d1]
./resolve() [0x1f6fadd]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f27fa8970b3]
./resolve() [0x1f6ed3d]
Signal Number = 6

----------------------------------------------------------------------
#TIME Sat Jun 13 12:39:23 2020 - Uptime 00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss)
#PROGRAM_NAME DaVinci Resolve v16.2.2.012 (Linux/Clang)

./resolve() [0x54bef69]
./resolve() [0x54be75a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0) [0x7f27fcb523c0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb) [0x7f27fa8b618b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x12b) [0x7f27fa895859]
./resolve(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0xed) [0x7229ecd]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x22086) [0x7f282d21b086]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x223f1) [0x7f282d21b3f1]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x22947) [0x7f282d21b947]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(__gxx_personality_v0+0x6c) [0x7f282d21be2c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1(_Unwind_RaiseException+0x166) [0x7f27faa730b6]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(__cxa_throw+0x66) [0x7f282d21aa16]
./resolve() [0x1fb2ddc]
./resolve() [0x1fb25a9]
./resolve() [0x1fac2cc]
./resolve() [0x1f7895c]
./resolve() [0x1f75a6e]
./resolve() [0x1f7444f]
./resolve() [0x1f73cf8]
./resolve() [0x1fadade]
./resolve() [0x54beb15]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0) [0x7f27fcb523c0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb) [0x7f27fa8b618b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x12b) [0x7f27fa895859]
./resolve(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0x15d) [0x7229f3d]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x22086) [0x7f282d21b086]
/opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libc++abi.so.1(+0x21a27) [0x7f282d21aa27]
./resolve() [0x1fb2ddc]
./resolve() [0x1fb25a9]
./resolve() [0x1fac2cc]
./resolve() [0x1f7895c]
./resolve() [0x1f75a6e]
./resolve() [0x1f7444f]
./resolve() [0x1f73cf8]
./resolve() [0x1f899d1]
./resolve() [0x1f6fadd]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f27fa8970b3]
./resolve() [0x1f6ed3d]
Signal Number = 6
```

My PC config:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2400g
- GPU: Embedded AMD Vega 8
- RAM: 16g
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Probably try reinstalling by following the steps shared on [foss linux](https://www.fosslinux.com/24381/how-to-install-davinci-resolve-on-ubuntu.htm). Provided you have [Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/) downloaded already.

1. Install required dependencies `sudo apt install xorriso libssl1.0.0 ocl-icd-opencl-dev fakeroot`
2. Download [MakeResolveDeb](http://www.danieltufvesson.com/makeresolvedeb) script.
3. Unzip both [Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/) and [MakeResolveDeb](http://www.danieltufvesson.com/makeresolvedeb). *Make sure the are both in the same directory*
4. Run either `./makeresolvedeb_*.sh lite` or `./makeresolvedeb_*.sh studio` in your terminal.
5. Finally, install the generated `.deb` package using the command `sudo dpkg -i davinci-resolve_*.deb`

I simply followed the instructions on the [post](https://www.fosslinux.com/24381/how-to-install-davinci-resolve-on-ubuntu.htm). You can refer to it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately, there is exactly the same problem after following these instructions. I installed all dependencies and tried to install the app several times.

Comment: @IvanBanha did you manage to resolve this at all?

Comment: @snim2 no, as I figured out the app requires proprietary OpenCL drivers from AMD. But I don't use this CPU/GPU anymore.